# Meaning of * in signature documentation

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

What does `*` mean in the function signature

```
_.extend(destination, *sources)
```

[See here](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) for an example.

Comment: my guess (hence this being a comment) is "zero or more comma delimited sources"

Comment: For what it's worth, this is strictly a notation they use in the documentation. The actual function is [declared as `_.extend = function(obj) { ... }`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore.js), i.e. only the first parameter is part of the actual function declaration; it accesses the "`*sources`" parameters via JavaScript's [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) pseudo-array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is notation borrowed from [Python](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) (search for "If the form “`*identifier`” is present"): it means that the formal parameter tagged with the asterisk will consume as many actual arguments as are left over after all other parameters are satisfied.  In Python, "as many as are left over" may be zero without error; I don't know if that's the case in underscore.js (which is implementing these semantics on top of the rather more primitive Javascript variadic function mechanism, so it can do whatever it likes).

Answer (score 1):

In that particular case it means that `_.extend` takes zero or more `source` objects. AFAIK, this notation is specific to Underscore (which probably picked it up from Ruby). The C-style `_.extend(destination, source, ...)` ellipses is an alternative (and possibly more common) way of noting the same thing.